# (non)existence certain smooth function of compact support.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $B$ be any real $m \times n$ matrix. Does there exist a differentiable (or, if possible, smooth) function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ of compact support such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{equation}
df(x) \propto B
\end{equation}
(So, to avoid any confusion, there exists a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{equation}
df(x) = g(x)B
\end{equation}
)

I stumbled on this question while looking for a certain trial function in the context of a variational problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some additional thinking on this myself and I think I've come to a fair enough resolution:

I'll assume $f$ is at least $C^2$: from the identity $\frac{\partial^2 f^i}{\partial x^j \partial x^k} = \frac{\partial^2 f^i}{\partial x^k \partial x^j}$ translates in this case to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j} B^i_k = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^k} B^i_j
\end{equation}
$\forall i,j,k$.

This says that the directional derivative in the direction of $B^i_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} - B^i_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ is zero, or equivalently $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}
g(...,x_j,...,x_k,...)=g(...,x_j+B^i_kt,...,x_k-B^i_jt,...)
\end{equation}
Since $f$ is nontrivial, there should be at least one nonzero $B^i_k$, and also $g$ should be nontrivial. Yet the above formula then shows that $g$ clearly can have no compact support (This discussion can be applied to the more general case where $f$ does not necessarily have compact support, but $df$ does)